# How can I open the webpage i´ve accessed with beautifulsoup in browser?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need a script which logs me into my git hub account and opens github page in browser. Till now it only gains access with beautifulsoup. I need a webpage to open with my account logged in. 
Thanks

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
from urllib.request import urlopen

login_data = {
'commit': 'Sign in',
'utf8': '✓',
'authenticity_token': 'willchange',
'login': 'maximmashkov',
'password': '12345',
'webauthn-support' : 'supported'
}

headers = {
'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
}


with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://github.com/session'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'html5lib')
    login_data['authenticity_token'] = soup.find('input', attrs = {'name': 'authenticity_token'})['value']
    response = requests.get(url)
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Please show us what you've done so far.

Comment: I can´ t paste the code here because t gives out an eror for no reason.

Comment: Edit your question to include your code.

Comment: --------------------------edited

Comment: Have you looked into using Selenium?

Comment: will it allow me to operate with bs4 in opened browser?

Comment: Yes definetely. Selenium with get you the dom and log your github by opening the webpage by itself. then you can scrape whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

First install selenium then according to your os install [chromediver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/) then test it by going to folder you have kept the driver and open terminal and type `chromedriver`, if there's no error then it works.

after that you need to use this code where you need to put your own path of chromedriver as executable path.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = "https://github.com/login"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= 'C:/Users/reckonsys/anshuman-work/product-analysis/productanalysis/chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)

emailid=driver.find_element_by_id("login_field")

emailid.send_keys("put your username")

passw=driver.find_element_by_id("password")

passw.send_keys("password here")

signin=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login"]/form/div[3]/input[4]')

signin.click()

time.sleep(10)

# get anything here......

driver.close()
```